# How to install Xtend 2.4 for Android?

Tags: eclipse, installation, windows-7-x64, xtend

I'm trying follow [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/march/article2.php)

When I try to 'Disable the checkbox Contact all update sites during install to find required software, to avoid unwanted updates of other Eclipse plug-ins.' I can't to make next steps because

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Xtend SDK 2.4.0.v201303201134 (org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group 2.4.0.v201303201134)
  Missing requirement: Xtend Standalone Bundle 2.4.0.v201303201134 (org.eclipse.xtend.standalone 2.4.0.v201303201134) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.codegen 2.5.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Xtend SDK 2.4.0.v201303201134 (org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group 2.4.0.v201303201134)
    To: org.eclipse.xtend.standalone [2.4.0.v201303201134]
```

Or I get error during installation in eclipse if enabale that checkbox.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
```

Comment: Work fine for me when i take Eclipse build with already installed Xtend SDK and installing the ADT Plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work fine for me when i take Eclipse build with already installed Xtend SDK and installing the ADT Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

to install Xtend but do not contact eclipse update site, you just need to add the EMF update site if not already done.
Help -> Install new Software -> Available Software sites -> Add...

http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/releases

After that disable all the Software sites except of EMF and Xtext (unfortunately I can't post images here)

Now, after closing with "Ok", choose work with Xtext update site. Select Xtend from the treeview, enable the "Contact all update sites" (unfortunately I can't post images here) and follow the next wizard steps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying all that on a classic Eclipse installation, without the Android plugins installed. Therefore please re-read the tutorial section "Setting up the IDE", it recommends to download and install th "all-in-one" bundle from the Android website or to manually install the ADT plugin into an existing Eclipse.

You should *not* uncheck the checkbox during the update. Eclipse will only add *necessary* updates to the list of plugins to be installed. And you can review that list once again in the installation wizard after Eclipse decided about the plugins.

Comment: No) be sure, i'm trying to do it on my current working eclipse-java-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64 with ADT plugin and on the ADT Bundle for windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Article assumes that you have a running Eclipse with EMF installed. This does not seem to be the case for you. Just leave 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' and it will properly install EMF.

Comment: yes. I've tried it, but got 'An error occurred while collecting items to be installed'. You can see full message at the top.

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685

Comment: I'll try to download Eclipse with Xtend SDK and istall ADT plugin there. Will see what happens)